# Install git and backup in dropbox

Tags: git, dropbox

I'am planning to create a git in my own server, but I need to know if its possible to create it and backup the final version of all the code to dropbox

This git will be in my own personal server

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, definitely.

Git is a distributed version control system, meaning even local copy is a separate repository. To copy the whole repository (and its content), you only need to copy the main directory (with `.git` directory at the top level of it).

Try it. Just create some repository, make some changes. Then copy the directory with your code (**including `.git` directory**) somewhere else, make some changes (without pulling / pushing from / to remotes) and check if the history of these two separate copies differs. If yes, you are doing it correctly, because by copying repository's directory you have just created another repository :)

Comment: Hi Tadeck, What I want to do its create an automatic copy in dropbox, because this automatically download in my laptop, desktop and backup in a HD. I want that all the code from my git backup automatically in dropbox

Comment: If Dropbox synchronizes also `.git` directory, then there should be no problem in achieving what you want. But remember that if `.git` is synchronized, someone having access to this dropbox copy will also have access to the history of the changes.

Comment: Yes i know that, but i think its the easiest way that I could backup this information, also the server will be backup but isn't the sam, or maybe implement a cronjob in my desktop that pull all projects and backup them in the HDD

Comment: @Ernesto: Any backup solution copying the whole directory with `.git` subdirectory will do the trick.